# Why isn't AJAX call reading my external PHP file?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have the following AJAX code that causes 2 things to happen when a form (`id="functionsquestionform2"`) is submitted:

1) Update MYSQL database using the code in frameworkajaxtest.php <--DOESN'T WORK

2) Fade in a div (`class = "incorrectanswermark"`) <--WORKS

The div fades in but the PHP code at frameworkajaxtest.php doesn't run. The PHP code executes correctly (the MYSQL database updates) when I include it directly within the file outside of this AJAX request, so I know it has something to do with AJAX reading the PHP code rather than the code itself. There are no console errors.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#functionsquestionform2').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url :  "frameworkajaxtest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
             $(".incorrectanswermark").fadeIn('slow');           
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is what I have in the external file frameworkajaxtest.php. It's long, but like I said, the code itself works fine so no need to read through it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['functions_question2'])){
    if($id){
        $res3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id");
        $data3 = $res3->fetch_array();
        if(isset($_SESSION['functions_question2']) && $_POST['functions_question2']==$_SESSION['functions_question2']){
            if($data3['FunctionsScore']<2)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET FunctionsScore = FunctionsScore+1 WHERE user_id=$id");
        }else{
            if($data3['FunctionsScore']>-2)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET FunctionsScore = FunctionsScore-1 WHERE user_id=$id");
        }
        if($data3['FunctionsPercent']>49 && $data3['FunctionsPercent']<100)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET FunctionsPercent = 2 WHERE user_id=$id");
    }else{
        $data3 = (array)$cookiedata;
        if(isset($_SESSION['functions_question2']) && $_POST['functions_question2']==$_SESSION['functions_question2']){
            if($data3['FunctionsScore']<2)$data3['FunctionsScore'] = $data3['FunctionsScore'] + 1;
        }else{
            if($data3['FunctionsScore']>-2)$data3['FunctionsScore'] = $data3['FunctionsScore'] - 1;
        }
        $cookiedata = $data3;
        $cookie = json_encode($data3);
        setcookie('guestdata', $cookie, time()+25920000);     
    }
}
if($id){
    $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id")->fetch_array();
}else{
    $data = (array)$cookiedata;
}
?>
```

Comment: `if($id)` you declared `$id` where?

Comment: It's declared at the top of my code (above the AJAX)  `<?php
include "inc/db.php";
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    echo 'Welcome, '.$_SESSION['name'].'!<br><br>';
}else{
.........`

Comment: The ajax and php are two different scripts. You said you declared it in your ajax, yet it is needed in your PHP. Full scripts?

Comment: There's probably a more elegant way to relay the full script, but I posted it in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/33kfbezf/      The PHP in the original post is the full script within the external file frameworkajaxtest.php